# R furure_map across multiple servers

Tags: r

When running the following:

```
rm(list = ls( a = T))
require(future)
require(furrr)

# machines
margot <- '192.168.1.99'
bakunin <- '192.168.1.29'

# set cluster
workers <- rep(c(margot, bakunin), each = 12L)
plan(cluster, workers = workers)

# data
n <- 10^3
x <- rpois(n, 100)


# function 
f <- function(x){
  .f <- function(i){sum(rlnorm(i, 9 , 2))}
  y <- furrr::future_map(x, .f = .f)
  quantile(y, .99)
}

# Map 
y <- f(x)
```

But it returns an error I truly do not understand where it comes from:

```
Error in map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress) : 
  could not find function "map_"
```

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated

Comment: My guess is that you have purrr 1.0.0 locally but purrr < 1.0.0 on your workers. If you try and update purrr on your workers to the CRAN version, does it work? This might also be a bug in the way furrr works though, so I'll also open an issue.

Comment: You were right. Version of R and purrr were not the same ob both machines. I upgraded both to R 4.2.2 and purrr 1.0.1.9000 but the error persists